# adjust uniformdeviate values

Tags: context, metapost

I need to insert in the rectangle all my 10 molecules in random way (angle and x,y position). I don't know what is wrong with my code.

[image]

```
\startMPinclusions

vardef spring (expr a, b, w, h, n) =
pair vec ; path pat ; numeric len ; numeric ang ;
vec := (b-a) ;
pat := for i=1 upto n-1: (if odd(i):-fi w/2,i)--endfor (0,n) ;
pat := (0,0)--(0,h)-- pat shifted (0,h)--(0,n+h)--(0,n+2h) ;
len := (xpart vec ++ ypart vec)/(n+2h) ;
ang := -90+angle(vec) ;
( pat yscaled len rotatedaround(origin,ang) shifted a )
enddef ; 

\stopMPinclusions

\enabletrackers
  [metapost.showlog]
\starttext

\starttext




\startMPcode
tracingall;
picture molecule;
path p ; p :=(.1cm,0)--spring((.2cm,0),(2.5cm,0),.5cm,0,10)--(2.6cm,0) ;

draw p;
draw fullcircle scaled 2cm shifted(-0.9cm,0);
draw fullcircle scaled 2cm shifted(3.6cm,0);
molecule := currentpicture scaled .1;currentpicture:=nullpicture;

numeric angulo; numeric xx; numeric yy; pair par;

for i=1 step 1 until 10:
angulo:=uniformdeviate 180;
xx:=uniformdeviate 80; 
yy:=uniformdeviate 50;
par:=(xx,yy);
draw molecule shifted par rotated angulo ;
endfor;

%clip currentpicture to (0,0)--(0,2cm)--(3cm,2cm)--(3cm,0)--cycle;
draw (0,0)--(0,2cm)--(3cm,2cm)--(3cm,0)--cycle withcolor 0.625red;
\stopMPcode

\stoptext
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replacing this

```
draw molecule shifted par rotated angulo ;
```

by this one

```
draw molecule rotated angulo shifted par;
```

gives a better (yet still not perfect) result:

[image]

(The rotation made by `rotated` is always centered at the origin, hence the former behavior. You can also use the line

```
draw molecule shifted par rotatedaround(par, angulo);
```

instead).

**EDIT**

I've just replaced the line defining your red bounding box,

```
 draw (((0,0)--(0,2cm)--(3cm,2cm)--(3cm,0)--cycle) withcolor 0.625red;
```

by

```
 draw (((0, 0)--(0, 50)--(80, 50)--(80, 0)--cycle) enlarged .46cm) withcolor 0.625red;
```

which is more precisely fitted to the parameters:

[image]